# Undefined JS error only in IE11

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I am getting this error only in IE 11. Basically a click button does not work and I am getting :

```
SCRIPT5009: 'search' is undefined
```

The calling code is:

```
<div>
   <p><b>Surname search:</b></p>
      <input id="searchBox" name="Search" placeholder="Search" type="text" value="" />
      <button onclick="search()">Search</button> 
           <div class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin" id="spinner" style="display: none;">
           </div>
</div>
```

This calls:

```
<script>
function search() {
    showSpinner();
    var searchString = $('#searchBox').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Search',
        data: ({ name: searchString}),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: response => updateTable(response),
    });
}


</script>
```

The key problem line in the calling code is:

```
 <button onclick="search()">Search</button>
```

Which creates the error:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'search' is undefined
```

This works fine in Chrome, Edge, Mozilla.

Finally JQuery library:

```
    <script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.8.3.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Much thanks in advance of any help.

My solution. I am putting it here as it was derived from the many comments.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<script>
    window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"><\/script>')
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
function search() {
    showSpinner();
    var searchString = $('#searchBox').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '/Search',
        data: ({ name: searchString}),
        dataType: 'html',
        success: updateTable
    });
}
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
   $('#btnSearch').click(function () {
       search();
   });
</script>
```

So I:

1) Upgraded to latest JQuery version

2) Sorted out my Search function:
    success: updateTable

3) Used JQuery correctly to handle the click event.

Thanks to all.

Comment: The global namespace is strange. What happens if you change the name of the function to "xxxsearch" instead of "search"?

Comment: Reason #562 why you should never use inline event handlers, especially when you're already working with jQuery. `<button id="myButton">` and `$( "#myButton" ).on( "click", function() ... )`

Comment: window.search might be a reserved method in IE

Comment: Also, `success: response => updateTable(response)` wont work in IE11. IE11 does not support ES6 syntax

Comment: Also why not just `success: updateTable,`

Comment: Also if inside a form, the form is submitted unless you add `type="button"` or use preventDefault

Comment: Lastly IE11 supports jQuery edge. 1.8 is REALLY old

Comment: Thank you for all of the comments. Already updated to 3.3.1, still a problem, so will work through the code

Comment: Can you please post the complete html file like where is script in head or at end of body. I tried to replicate this but working for me in IE11

Comment: Sorted. I have benefitted from all of your advice so will post what I have done. Huge thanks